# Error with cpanel migrated account (PEAR/MDB2)

Tags: php, pear, cpanel, mdb2

I had a site in a cpanel server working well but when I have migrated it to a new one, I have a MDB2 error  related.

**Fatal error: Call to a member function tableInfo() on a non-object in /home/lubrican/public_html/clientes/PEAR/MDB2.php on line 2547**

( php code: http://pastebin.com/N7jf5Mkf )

I've  migrated the site with the standard cpanel tools and all files looks complete.

The MDB2 library seems work because I can do any search in the database.

The issue is when I add a record to the database.

Any hint ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not have the latest version of MDB2. Make sure to install version `2.5.0b3`. It's marked beta, but very stable.
If the problem happens again, report back.

Comment: Which errors do you get now? Line 2547 is `if (PEAR::isError($result)) {`.